# Vuex store module returning null when called from router

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue-router

I have to access Vuex store from the router. Specifically, in the `beforeEach()` method. Which I do like this:

#### `/src/router/index.js`

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import store from '../store/index.js'

Vue.use(VueRouter)

const routes = [
// The routes goes here
]

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes
})

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  console.log(store.getters)
  // This prints an object that does contain 'auth/user' sub-object,
  // but I have to click on an ellipsis to show the value in the console.
  console.log(store.getters['auth/user'])
  // This prints null for some reason.

  if (to.name !== 'Login' && !store.getters['auth/user']) {
    next('/login')
  } else {
    next()
  }
})
```

The Vuex module is namespaced and can be accessed normally in components.

```js
export default {
  namespaced: true,
  state: {
    user: null
  },
  getters: {
    user (state) {
      return state.user
    },
    // Other getters
  }
}

Is there a workaround to this?
```

Comment: as it prints null you can access it ... so most likly some issue with your getter declaration?

Comment: Can you share your store, specifically the `auth` module? Are you sure the `null` isn't expected? You could test this by setting a default value `'foo'` to be returned from the getter

Comment: I see the problem now. `state.user` is initialized as null and then populated by Firebase Auth. During routing, specifically after page refresh, Firebase Auth hasn't got the chance to do its job.

Comment: @starleaf1 how can we let firebase auth do the job? I am having the same problem.