# Using vuex store within router

Tags: vuex, quasar-framework, vuex-modules

I have a vuex store I can access in components, but I am trying to access the store within a Vue app in the Quasar framework, and I cannot access the store.

I am not sure if I'm not importing the store correctly. This is the closes question I could find, but it wasn't answered completedly: [Vuex store module returning null when called from router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62764333/vuex-store-module-returning-null-when-called-from-router)

router/index.js

```
import { route } from "quasar/wrappers";
import {
  createRouter,
  createMemoryHistory,
  createWebHistory,
  createWebHashHistory,
} from "vue-router";
import routes from "./routes";
import { useStore } from "vuex";

import { computed, ref } from "vue";

const store = useStore();

export default route(function (/* { store, ssrContext } */) 
{
  const store = useStore();
  console.log(store); <--RETURNS UNDEFINED-------

  const createHistory = omitted

  const Router = createRouter({
    omitted
  });

   <--THIS IS WHAT I'M TRYING TO IMPLEMENT, BUT CAN'T 
ACCESS (BUT NOTE THAT I CAN'T EVEN ACCESS THE STORE ABOVE)
   Router.beforeEach(function (to, _, next) {
     
     if (to.meta.requiresAuth && 
!store.state.auth.isAuthenticated) {
       next("/auth");
     } else if (to.meta.requiresUnauth && 
store.state.auth.isAuthenticated) {
       next("/coaches");
     } else {
       
       next();
     }
   });
  
  return Router;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to change this line:

```
export default route(function ({ store, ssrContext } */) {
```

to this:

```
export default route(function ({ store} ) {
```

I'm not sure why I couldn't import the store other ways, but a win is a win!